# Durable Azure Functions and Integration Tests

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, integration-testing, azure-durable-functions

I'm trying to test (integration tests) my Azure Durable Function v3 with SpecFlow and MSTest.

Functions are initialized with DI and Startup class:

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);
        }
...
```

Orchestrator entry point is triggered by HTTP endpoint:

```cs
public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(Function1))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DoYourJob(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, methods: "post", Route = "api/routes/function1")] HttpRequestMessage httpRequest,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
...
```

My IntegrationTest constructor initializes Az Function with `HostBuilder` (thanks to this [article](https://saebamini.com/integration-testing-in-azure-functions-with-dependency-injection/)):

```cs
[Binding]
public sealed class Function1StepDefinitions
{
    private readonly IHost _host;
    private readonly Function1 _function;

    public Function1StepDefinitions()
    {
        var startup = new MyNamespace.Functions.Startup();
        _host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(config =>
            {
                config.AddDurableTask(options =>
                {
                    options.HubName = "MyTaskHub";
                });

                startup.Configure(config);
            })
            .ConfigureServices(ReplaceTestOverrides)  // Method to replace/mock some external services
            .Build();

        _function = new Function1(Host.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions..., ..);
```

And in my test I dont know how to retrieve `IDurableOrchestrationClient` to call my HTTP Trigger:

```cs
    [When(@"I call my function")]
    public async Task WhenICallMyFunction()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

        await _function.DoYourJob(
            request,
            Host.Services.GetService<IDurableOrchestrationClient>()); // This is always null
...
```

Is there a way to retrieve this `IDurableOrchestrationClient` and test my whole Function (with Orchestrator and Activities calls)?

Comment: This is my exact scenario (down to the article I used to ensure my DI would be the same as the system under test). Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Still no, for the moment I did my integration tests on deployed environment (without mocking anything...).

Comment: Running into the same issue with a Durable Entity. Would be really nice if there's a way to test it in a CI/CD pipeline without actual deployment. Started a bounty, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a `IDurableClientFactory` that you can inject instead based on [this code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/66f54508951a5fa9946e18f89551c508cd44cc07/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskJobHostConfigurationExtensions.cs#L91).

Using this, you can create a client to use as shown in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/47247f9ab322efdf9cd9216582bc5a7dce9bb37f/samples/functionapp-csharp/ClientFunction.cs).